# how to convert objectid of mongodb child collection to string inplace during aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, pymongo

I have two collections like this:

```py
# col1
[
  {
    _id: '5ec878f79c87a300127ec503',
    name: 'dim'
  },
  {...},
]
```

```py
# col2
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId('5ec8da619c87a30012f41d0b'),
    record_id: '5ec878f79c87a300127ec503',
    tags: 'authenticated'
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId('5ec8da619c87a30012ffdsk1'),
    record_id: '5ec878f79c87a300127ec503',
    tags: 'pre'
  },
]
```

I want to **join two collections into one** and **convert col2._id from objectid to string**.

heres my aggregate query:

```py
col1.aggregate(
  [
    {'$lookup': {
       'from': 'col2',
       'localField': '_id',
       'foreignField': 'record_id',
       'as': 'records'
    }},
    {'$project': {'records._id': {'$toString': '$records._id'}}}
  ]
)
```

The result I except should be like this:

```py
# result
[
  {
    '_id': '5ec878f79c87a300127ec503',
    'name': 'dim',
    'records': [
        {
          '_id': '5ec8da619c87a30012f41d0b',
          'record_id': '5ec878f79c87a300127ec503',
          'tags': 'authenticated'
        },
        {
          '_id': '5ec8da619c87a30012ffdsk1',
          'record_id': '5ec878f79c87a300127ec503',
          'tags': 'pre'
        },
      ]
  }
]
```

but I got an error.

```py
Unsupported conversion from array to string in $convert with no onError value
```

I also tried **$addFields** and **$map**. It either override records and return an array, or create a new field. that not what I want.

```py
{'$addFields': {
  'records': {
    '$map': {
        'input': '$records',
        'as': 'r',
        'in': {'$toString': '$$r._id'}
      }
    }
}}
```

So my question is: **how to convert col2._id from objectid to string inplace during aggregate?**

Comment: You can use the aggregate operator [$toString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/index.html).

Comment: I tried, the problem is child collection

Comment: You should use a `$lookup`'s _pipeline_ for matching - in this case.

Comment: I did, and I got a new collection, the col2 is now col1s field. but how to convert col2. _id to string without any new field?. I re-edit this question btw, perhaps u should check it again:)

Comment: Please post your query and the output - and explain what is it you want from it.

Comment: sure thing, u can check it again, all i want is convert objectid to string during aggregation query. sorry about my confusion

Comment: You have to use the `$map` on the `records` array - you have posted some code. It needs some correction. Use [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/index.html) to merge the existing fields with the transformed `_id` field (that is after applying the `$toString`).

Comment: In your `$addFields` stage, the `$map`'s `in` parameter value should be: `in: { $mergeObjects: [ "$$r", { "_id": { $toString: "$$r._id" }} ] }`. This your solution.

Comment: okay! I'll try it, thank u

Answer (score 0):

you can try below option where we first convert id to String and store as a convertedIdStr and then using that we do a lookup.

```
[
 {
  "$addFields": {
     "convertedIdStr": {
        "$toString": "$_id"
     }
  }
    },
 {
  "$lookup": {
     "from": "test",
     "localField": "convertedIdStr",
     "foreignField": "record_id",
     "as": "records"
  }
 }
]
```

Hope this helps!
Note We run this aggregation on col1 (collection1)